# Debugging QGIS from Visual Studio

Tags: qgis-3, visual-studio, debugging, compile, compilation

I try setup a QGIS debug environment under Windows10 64bit.
I followed the instrictions given at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL#L423

I also had a look at 
https://www.shaeffer.co/compiling-qgis-on-windows/
and
https://www.cursosgis.com/compilar-y-debuggear-qgis-en-windows/

When I try to start debugging in Visual Studio I get following error message:

```
Could not load qgis_app.dll
module not found
Check D:\Projects\QGIS\ms-windows\osgeo4w\build-qgis-test-x86_64\output\bin\RelWithDebInfo\qgis.env for correct environment paths.
```

The `qgis_app.dll` exists in the `QGIS\ms-windows\osgeo4w\build-qgis-test-x86_64\output\bin\RelWithDebInfo` folder.

During the build there is a crash of the `crssync.exe` which is called during the build:

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname:   crssync.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    0.0.0.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    5ddd3d2f
  Fehlermodulname:  qgis_core.dll
  Fehlermodulversion:   6.3.9600.19464
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   5d6727f2
  Ausnahmecode: c0000135
  Ausnahmeoffset:   00000000000ecf30
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  ac05
  Zusatzinformation 2:  ac0507478d1c5bd693cfc4fe3987e900
  Zusatzinformation 3:  ac05
  Zusatzinformation 4:  ac0507478d1c5bd693cfc4fe3987e900
```

What can I do to narrow down the source of the error and get Visual Developer to build the `ALL_Build` successfully?

The error messages vary. often the module syncsrsdb and qgis_core fail but sometimes also other modules cause trouble:
One example for error messages:

```
    129>------ Build started: Project: qgis_authcryptotest, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------
127>       CustomBuild:
127>         Running crssync
127>     1>
127>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
127>
127>Build FAILED.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x86\Version.Lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

C:\Projects\QGIS\ms-windows\osgeo4w\build-qgis-test-x86_64\output\bin\RelWithDebInfo\qgis_core.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

One message looks like a problem caused by a mixture between 32bit and 64 bit components

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x86\Version.Lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'")
```

but I could not find any special 64 bit versions of the Windows SDK

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: Have you checked the qgis.env file mentioned?

Comment: @til_b: I have running debug enviroments where qtcreator is used instead of visual studio and there is also no *.env file, so I guess the qgis.env file ist not neccessary for debugging

Comment: Check folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um . You shall find x86, x64, arm, arm64. You need x64.

Comment: Here you have my notes to do it in windows,They work because I work in windows, https://www.cursosgis.com/compilar-y-debuggear-qgis-en-windows/  , is in spanish but you can use google translate

Comment: My notes should work for you because I work with the core of qgis in windows.

Comment: @FranRaga: I followed your instructions (mentioned in the question above :-)  ) but it doesn't  work. I guess something in the codebase of QGIS changed so it doesn't work with a new setup anymore. Perhaps the change to proj6 /7

Comment: Maybe, I'd have to try the new version then.

Comment: @FranRaga: with qtcreator I can build the current version but with visual studio i tried it on 4 different computers now to make sure the problem has nothing to do with a specific environment of a computer and it fails on all of them

Comment: I'll try the new dev branch then.

Comment: is VisuaStudio you are using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @MyGIS: it's the one that was linked in the instructions mentioned above. It's a 32 bit version but there doesn't seem to exist a 64 bit version: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2516445 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27686632/6559211. The active solution platform is set to x64 in Visual Studio

Comment: I've tried the current dev version and it still works following my notes https://www.cursosgis.com/compilar-y-debuggear-qgis-en-windows/. The only thing is that I had to add Version.lib to qgis_core and on the other hand the file qgis.env did not create it for me, so I added it manually. I've tested it in a clean windows 10 64bits laptop. Screenshot https://imgur.com/gallery/k1RzLrF

Comment: @FranRaga: Thanks for testing it and your information.The build was successful after adding Version-lib on one of my machines but debugging still doesn't work because of the missing qgis_app.dll. How does your qgis.env look like? does it point to the qgis-rel-dev folder of the OsGeo4W64-folder?

Comment: @FranRaga: how many files does your C:\Projects\QGIS\ms-windows\osgeo4w\build-qgis-test-x86_64\output\bin\RelWithDebInfo contain? the one built by Visual studio contains only 26 files. The output\bin folder created by QTCreator where I can debug QGIS has more than 700 files in it.

Comment: Yes,you can copy this file or create using the compilelog file!

Comment: it would be nice if you shared your notes to use qtcreator on win

Comment: ok. one step further... with the env file of the rel-dev QGIS starts when i choose "start debugging" but without python support...  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~2/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 25, in 
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.

Comment: I will write down my notes for debugging with QTCreator as soon as I have done the setup again one a different PC. during my current setup I changed settings /setup so often until it worked that I need to recap the proper steps ;-)

Comment: I changed QGIS_PREFIX_PATH to C:\Projects\QGIS\ms-windows\osgeo4w\build-qgis-test-x86_64\output and now the python support workd :-) Yay! Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put as an answer the steps I've followed.

You have to follow my notes described in this [post](https://www.cursosgis.com/compilar-y-debuggear-qgis-en-windows/), BUT you will have to make some changes.

When you open the Visual Studio solution with the `devenv` command, DON'T DO THE BUILD, wait a bit.

Go to **qgis_core** properties and add **Version.lib**

Now do the build and go out for a drink as this takes a long time.

[image]

To debug remember to have the symbols installed and placed in your project

[image]

and in the project

[image]

In my case I also have installed the Qt plugin for Visual studio 2015.

[image]

And run debug.

[image]

I'm using this version, updated yesterday and Windows 10 64 bits

https://github.com/All4Gis/QGIS

https://github.com/All4Gis/QGIS/commit/e75d0f858687808c51d4578c94001b63c6eee233

I hope it helps.

Comment: It's strange that only half of the bounty is awarded even if the answer is marked as correct. I thought I would have 6 days to award the bounty manually but in my inbox there is a message ..."answer auto-selected"

Comment: You have to accept the answer within bounty's period, not afterwards.