# synccrsdb build error

Tags: qgis-3

I am trying to build QGIS 3.10 on Windows x64 and follow INSTALL file.

I am getting following error

```
2>------ Build started: Project: version, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------  
2>------ Build started: Project: qgis_core_autogen, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------  
2>  Automatic MOC for target qgis_core  
3>------ Build started: Project: crssync, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------  
3>  crssync.vcxproj -> C:\project\QGIS-release-3_12_vs14\ms-windows\osgeo4w\build-qgis-test-x86_64\output\bin\RelWithDebInfo\crssync.exe  
3>  crssync.vcxproj -> C:/project/QGIS-release-3_12_vs14/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-test-x86_64/apps/qgis-test/pdb/crssync.pdb (Full PDB)  
4>------ Build started: Project: synccrsdb, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------  
4>  Running crssync  
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.  
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Earlier solutions as described in http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Build-qgis-errors-td5219922.html unable to solve the problem as it is based on Qt4.

I had also tried [Debugging QGIS from Visual Studio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340984/debugging-qgis-from-visual-studio) and https://www.shaeffer.co/compiling-qgis-on-windows    but no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Run all the necessary batch files before starting devenv.exe from that command shell.

1. %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\OS4Geo4W-dev.bat
2. %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal-dev-env.bat
3. devenv.exe

Long answer: I also ran into this while trying to build QGIS on Windows. Thanks to your link I was able to figure out the problem.

KaburNaj said:

> The ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(synccrsdb ...) action in QGIS/src/crssync/CMakeLists.txt file causes a command-line call to the Build/output/bin/Release/crssync.exe file during the build action for the synccrsdb package. It turns out that crssync.exe has a dependency on qca.dll so this action returns the rather uninformative error code -1073741515 (which apparently means "missing DLL").

Running crssync.exe from the command line, I got these three alert messages:

```
---------------------------
crssync.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because gdal302.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------

---------------------------
crssync.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Core.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------

---------------------------
crssync.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Xml.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------
```

After running `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\OS4Geo4W-dev.bat`, I no longer got the missing Qt5 dlls. Only missing gdal and proj dll alerts.
After running `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal-dev-env.bat`, it runs and builds without errors.